# how to upload file to google drive using sdk in uploadtype=media

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, rhomobile

I am trying to upload file to google drive.
as

token_res = Rho::AsyncHttp.post(
  :url => "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media",
  :headers => {'Content-Type'=> 'image/jpg','Content-Transfer-Encoding'=> 'base64', 'Authorization'=> tokn_final ,'X-JavaScript-User-Agent'=> 'Google APIs Explorer' },
  :body => image_path
    )

A file is uploaded, if i give string in body as :body=> 'some string...'
But if i give the image_path in the body, it is not uploading the file, it only uploading the path of the file as string.

i dono how to upload the file, pls help me to upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the image as binary encoded to the body, not the image's path. If you are using the Ruby client lib, it's quite easier.

```
drive = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')
media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(file_name, mime_type)
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => drive.files.insert,
  :media => media,
  :parameters => {'uploadType' => 'media'}
)
```